# salt-stack highstate - find slow states

Tags: salt-stack

Running an initial install takes about 20 minutes, running a `salt-call state.highstate` takes about 6 minutes. That's not unreasonable, but I'd like to speed it up, but I'm not sure how to find the slowest states.

Is there any way to find how long each state takes to run other than watching my screen with a stopwatch for 6 minutes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sudo salt-call state.highstate` provides start-time and duration for each state.

```
----------
          ID: ntp-removed
    Function: pkg.removed
      Result: True
     Comment: None of the targeted packages are installed
     Started: 12:45:04.430901
    Duration: 0.955 ms
     Changes:
```

You can capture this for processing:

```
salt-call state.highstate test=True --out json | tee output.json
python -c 'import json; j=json.load(open("output.json"))["local"];\
           print [x["name"] for x in j.values() if x["duration"] > 1000];'

[u'munin-node']
```