# salt-stack - show Started and Duration details in results

Tags: salt-stack

I'm running the same salt states on vagrant and on a cloud server. On vagrant the Started and Duration details show, but on the cloud server they don't.

I'm running masterless on v2014.7.5 (Helium)

Here's my vagrant config:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "trusty64"
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.11"
    config.vm.synced_folder "saltMount/", "/srv/saltMount/"
    config.vm.provision "salt" do |salt|
        salt.minion_config = "minion"
        salt.run_highstate = true
        salt.colorize = true
        salt.log_level = 'info'
        salt.verbose = true
    end
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.memory = 1024
    end
end
```

Here is my minion file:

```
master: localhost
file_client: local
failhard: True
state_verbose: True

file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/saltMount/stateFiles

pillar_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/saltMount/pillars
```

And this is the command I'm running:

```
salt-call state.highstate -l info
```

What am I missing to get the Duration and Started on my cloud highstate?

(This is a followup question to: [salt-stack highstate - find slow states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852817/) )

Comment: Try: `state_output: full` in your conf file.

Comment: Finally managed to try it. I put `state_output: full` in my `/etc/salt/minion` but still no duration or started. Any other ideas?